# Customizing Spring Data repository bean names for use with multiple data sources

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have a project that utilizes Spring Data (MongoDB in this instance) to interact with multiple databases with the same schema.  What this means is that each database utilizes the same entity and repository classes.  So, for example:

```
public class Thing {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    // etc...  
}

public interface ThingRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Thing, String> {
    List<Thing> findByName(String name);
}

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = { ThingRepository.class })
public MongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    // Standard mongo config
}
```

This works fine if I am connecting to a single database, but things get more complicated when I want to connect to more than one database at the same time:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = { ThingRepository.class },
    mongoTemplateRef = "mongoTemplateOne")
public MongoConfigOne extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplateOne")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(this.mongo(), "db_one");
    }

    // Remaining standard mongo config

}

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = { ThingRepository.class },
    mongoTemplateRef = "mongoTemplateTwo")
public MongoConfigTwo extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplateTwo")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(this.mongo(), "db_two");
    }

    // Remaining standard mongo config

}
```

I can create multiple instances of the same repository, using different `MongoTemplate` instances, but I don't know the correct way to reference and inject them.  I would like to be able to inject the individual repository instances into different controllers, like so:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/things/one/")
public class ThingOneController {
    @Resource private ThingRepository thingRepositoryOne;
    ...
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/things/two/")
public class ThingTwoController {
    @Resource private ThingRepository thingRepositoryTwo;
    ...
}
```

Is a configuration like this possible?  Can I somehow control the bean names of the instantiated interfaces so that I can reference them with `@Resource` or `@Autowired`?

Bonus question: can this be accomplished with a custom repository factory as well?

Comment: You might have to manually instantiate the repository implementations using the factory, at which point you could name them using the normal `@Bean` techniques.

Comment: @chrylis: Could you provide an example of this as an answer?  Not really sure what the best way to create a factory bean and repository instances would look like.

Comment: I have only poked around at manual creation, and I can't give you good advice on that point. It's likely Oliver Gierke will be around in a few hours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create your repository interface with `@NoRepositoryBean`, we'll wire it up ourself:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ModelMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<Model, String> {
}
```

Then, in a `@Configuration` class, instantiate the 2 repository beans using `MongoRepositoryFactoryBean`. Both repositories will return the same Spring Data Repository interface, but we'll assign them different `MongoOperations` (ie: database details):

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class MongoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("one")
    public ModelMongoRepository modelMongoRepositoryOne() throws DataAccessException, Exception {
        MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<ModelMongoRepository, Model, String> myFactory = new MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<ModelMongoRepository, Model, String>();
        myFactory.setRepositoryInterface(ModelMongoRepository.class);
        myFactory.setMongoOperations(createMongoOperations("hostname1", 21979, "dbName1", "username1", "password1"));
        myFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return myFactory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("two")
    public ModelMongoRepository modelMongoRepositoryTwo() throws DataAccessException, Exception {
        MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<ModelMongoRepository, Model, String> myFactory = new MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<ModelMongoRepository, Model, String>();
        myFactory.setRepositoryInterface(ModelMongoRepository.class);
        myFactory.setMongoOperations(createMongoOperations("hostname2", 21990, "dbName2", "username2", "password2"));
        myFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return myFactory.getObject();
    }

    private MongoOperations createMongoOperations(String hostname, int port, String dbName, String user, String pwd) throws DataAccessException, Exception {
        MongoCredential mongoCredentials = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(user, dbName, pwd.toCharArray());
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(hostname, port), Arrays.asList(mongoCredentials));
        Mongo mongo = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, dbName).getDb().getMongo();
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo, dbName);
    }
    //or this one if you have a connection string
    private MongoOperations createMongoOperations(String dbConnection) throws DataAccessException, Exception {
        MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(dbConnection);
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);
        Mongo mongo = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, mongoClientURI.getDatabase()).getDb().getMongo();
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo, mongoClientURI.getDatabase());
    }
}
```

You now have 2 beans with distinct `@Qualifier` names, each configured for different databases, and using the same model.

You can inject them using `@Qualifier` :

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("one")
private ModelMongoRepository mongoRepositoryOne;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("two")
private ModelMongoRepository mongoRepositoryTwo;
```

For simplicity, I've hard coded the values in the configuration class, but you can inject them from properties in application.properties/yml.

> **EDIT to answer comments:**

Here's the modification if you want to create a custom implementation without loosing the benefits of spring data interface repositories. the specs says this:

> Often it is necessary to provide a custom implementation for a few
>   repository methods. Spring Data repositories easily allow you to
>   provide custom repository code and integrate it with generic CRUD
>   abstraction and query method functionality. To enrich a repository
>   with custom functionality you first define an interface and an
>   implementation for the custom functionality. Use the repository
>   interface you provided to extend the custom interface. The most
>   important bit for the class to be found is the Impl postfix of the
>   name on it compared to the core repository interface (see below).

Create a new interface, which has technically nothing to do with spring data, good old interface:

```
public interface CustomMethodsRepository {
    public void getById(Model model){
}
```

Have your repository interface extends this new interface:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ModelMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<Model, String>, CustomMethodsRepository {
}
```

Then, create your implementation class, which **only** implements your non-spring-data interface:

```
public class ModelMongoRepositoryImpl  implements CustomModelMongoRepository {
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public ModelMongoRepositoryImpl(MongoOperations mongoOperations) {
        this.mongoOperations = mongoOperations;
    }
    public void getById(Model model){
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Change the Java configuration to add `myFactory.setCustomImplementation(new ModelMongoRepositoryImpl());` :

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("one")
public ModelMongoRepository modelMongoRepositoryOne() throws DataAccessException, Exception {
    MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<ModelMongoRepository, Model, String> myFactory = new MongoRepositoryFactoryBean<ModelMongoRepository, Model, String>();
    MongoOperations mongoOperations = createMongoOperations("hostname1", 21979, "dbName1", "usdername1", "password1");
    myFactory.setCustomImplementation(new ModelMongoRepositoryImpl(mongoOperations));
    myFactory.setRepositoryInterface(ModelMongoRepository.class);
    myFactory.setMongoOperations(mongoOperations);

    myFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return myFactory.getObject();
}
```

If you were not wiring the repository manually through Java config, this implementation would HAVE to be named `ModelMongoRepositoryImpl` to match the interface `ModelMongoRepository +"Impl"`. And it would be handled automatically by spring.

Comment: What do I do in cases where I have added custom methods, such as with `ThingRepository.findByName()`?  Or if I have custom implemented methods in a `ThingRepositoryImpl` class?  Do I need to manually implement them in my concrete class that Spring will be injecting the `MongoTemplate` into?  If so, then what is the point of even using Spring Data's repository factory?

Comment: I see what you mean, I'll update the code to use an Interface + MongoRepositoryFactoryBean

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will work, but now I am hung up on how to inject the `MongoTemplates` into an `ThingRepositoryImpl` should I want to custom implement `findByName(..)` or another method.  Thoughts?

Comment: Here, I believe this is the final solution you were looking for! Go over the the last part ("Edit to answer comments"). You can achieve your goal with minimal code.

Comment: That did the trick!  In my case, I also had to add the line `myFactory.setRepositoryBaseClass(MyBaseRepository.class);` since I have a base repository class that extends `SimpleMongoRepository`, but otherwise, the configuration worked as described.  This was an enormous help, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For a general `@Repository` you can just add `(value="someDao")` to name the created Bean, if the `MongoRepository` extends `Repository` this should work.

Comment: That doesn't help me, because more than one instance of each repository is being created.  Using `@Repository(name="myRepository")` will result in two beans with the same name.  I want to make sure that objects created by the repository factory bean are named differently and programatically.

Comment: You can do this @Autowire @Qualifier("mongoTemplateOne")

Comment: I am not trying to inject the individual `MongoTemplate` objects, I am trying to inject the repositories they are being used to create.  In the example I have provided, how would you inject the `ThingRepository` created with either data source?

Comment: How do you get the repository from the wired mongoTemplate?