# Can I use a HashMap to pick which interface (DAO) to autowire in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interface, dao

I will try to be as detailed as possible. I have many DAO and my service needs to use one of them based on the key i get. For instance -

```
if(key.equals("abc") {
   obj = abcDAO.getOne(id);
} else if(key.equals("xyz") {
   obj = xyzDAO.getOne(id);
}
```

The object is of type parent class and abc, xyz.. are all child classes.

My idea is to create a `Map<String, ParentCLass>` to get the object just by passing the key instead of If-else so that it will be easy to add for further changes. In case it would've been a normal class, I wouldv'e initialized the map as

```
Map<String, ParentClass> map. 
map.put("abc", new Abc());
```

But since DAO are interfaces and require to be @Autowired for using them, I don't know how to proceed. I am a beginner. Any help appreciated.

Comment: you can use polymorphism instead, check this [exemple](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

Answer (score 4):

Spring is able to inject all beans with the same interface in a map if the map has String as key (will contain the bean names) and the interface as value.

```
public interface MyDao {
    
}

@Autowired
private Map<String, MyDao> daos;
```

**EDIT:** If you use Spring Data Repository, there is already a tagging Interface: Repository. You can use below code to inject all DAOs in one bean.

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, Repository> daos;
```

**EDIT2:** Example

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> { ... }

@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, Repository> daos;

    public List<User> findAll() {
        return daos.get("userRepo").findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, but what do I put in the map? like daos.put("key", new AbcDAO()) won't work right? since it would mean instantiating abstract class..

Comment: nothing Spring will fill the map with all beans implemting the same interface for you. You can get them by bean name. My mistake, I updated no need to new HashMap.

Comment: umm, i am confused now. I have different repositories.  In your example, My User will be User1, User2 , etc for all the repositories. I want to pick that using map, I will be defining a key which is a string and value as the repository that I want. A design like that..

Comment: sorry, I am lost too... If you can add a sample of 2 repository you want to retrieve with their key.

Comment: See.. i have 2 repositories with classes  public interface AbcDAO extends JpaRepositor<Abc, Long> and public interface XyzDao extends JpaRepository<Xyz, Long> Now based on input value, I will select which dao to autowire. So my idea is to use Map<String, Repository> the string is the key(suppost "pick abc") and value will be the dao obj. so I need a statement like map.put("pick abc", new AbcDao()). But this will give me an error since I cannot instantiate. Is there a way to accomplish adding the dao to the map?

Comment: If you use my sample, you can retrieve keys: abcDAO or xyzDao. If you want custom bean name to have keys like "pick abc" this is much more complex here is a post about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337453/customizing-spring-data-repository-bean-names-for-use-with-multiple-data-sources As an alternative you can have a map with aliases for the daos: daos.get(aliases.get("pick abc"))

Comment: okay, then for the sample that you have written, what would be "userRepo" ? for my scenario. I mean how would I be using the map in my service to get one dao?

Answer (score 0):

You can create different bean for each of your Dao with a specific name

```
@Bean(name = "daoImpl1")
public Dao daoImpl1(){
return new DaoImpl1();

@Bean(name = "daoImpl2")
public Dao daoImpl2(){
return new DaoImpl2();
```

And then `@Autowire` them using `@Qualifier` with that name

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("daoImpl1")
private Dao daoImpl1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("daoImpl2")
private Dao daoImpl2;
```

Answer (score 0):

i made methods to make simple jpa things,
i stored all of repositories in the HashMap
you just have to pass the child class and you get the corresponding JpaRepository

you can see more at https://github.com/fajaralmu/base_web_app

example :

```
public List<Page> getAllPages() {
        List<Page> allPages = entityRepository.findAll(Page.class);
        
        return   allPages;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: which is the webconfigservice that you are using to get JpaRepository?

Comment: class i made.. please check my repo https://github.com/fajaralmu/base_web_app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fajar/entitymanagement/service/WebConfigService.java